# YAML Scanner Error: Mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: postgresql, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, yaml

I am trying to deploy my PostgreSQL to a docker container (in an EC2 instance). My YAML file looks like this:

```
version: ‘3’
service:
  postgres:
  image: ‘postgres: 13.0’
  ports:
    - “5432:5432”
```

This works in my localhost. However, when I run 'docker-compose up -d' in the EC2 instance, an error is returned:

> ```
> ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here in "./docker-compose.yml", line 4, column 19
> ```

I have searched similar threads and tried all possible solutions but to no avail.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compose file has incorrect structure. Indent matters in YAML syntax. So you need to fix it to

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres: 13.0'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Check the example here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

**P.S.** - There are also `service` instead of `services` and incorrect quotations in your yaml. Like `‘` instead of `'` and `“` instead of `"`.

Comment: thanks, but the compose file I posted works in my local host. For some reason, the exact yaml file in my question doesn't work in the EC2 instance

Comment: Doublecheck it is the same byte-to-byte. Probably some chars were converted improperly when you copy-paste the code to AWS..

Comment: @jpineds because `‘` in your yaml is actually not `'` and `“` is actually not `"`..

Comment: Thanks, I changed the quotation marks and now I got a different error: ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Invalid top-level property "service". Valid top-level sections for this Compose file are: services, networks, volumes, version, and extensions starting with "x-".

Comment: Are you sure you have that working locally? :) Check my updated yaml. I fixed the structure.

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried your solution. It seem to have accepted the syntax, but another error was displayed. I will probably create another ticket for this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred if you have invalid .yaml structure.

Please validate the file content and structure.

I have the same issue and due to that I was facing the issue.